# How to convert distinct values in the original columns to new columns with dummy?

Tags: python, pandas

Original dataframe:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {"id":[1001,1002,1003,1004],
     "is_male":[1,0,0,1],
     "is_elder":[0,0,0,1],
     "timeline":["b1","b2","c","b1"]}
    )
```

It looks like:

| id | is_male | is_elder | timeline |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1 | 0 | b1 |
| 1002 | 0 | 0 | b2 |
| 1003 | 0 | 0 | c |
| 1004 | 1 | 1 | b1 |

There are three distinct values in `timeline`(it actually has more than 10 distinct values), what I want is let the distinct values be the new columns, such that `b1,b2,c`.

Expected output:

| id | is_male | is_elder | timeline | b1 | b2 | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1 | 0 | b1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1002 | 0 | 0 | b2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1003 | 0 | 0 | c | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1004 | 1 | 1 | b1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

What I have tried is to define three function, which is not a effective way if there are lots of distinct values:

```
def f(df):
    if df['timeline'] == 'b1':
        val = 1
    else:
        val = 0
    return val

df2['b1'] = df2.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Could anyone tell me smart ways to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.get_dummy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) and get your `dummy dataframe` from the `timeline column` then use [`pandas.concatenate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html#concatenating-with-mixed-ndims) and concat old dataframe and dummy dataframe to one dataframe like below:

```
>>> pd.concat([df2, pd.get_dummies(df2['timeline'])], axis=1)
     id  is_male  is_elder timeline  b1  b2  c
0  1001        1         0       b1   1   0  0
1  1002        0         0       b2   0   1  0
2  1003        0         0        c   0   0  1
3  1004        1         1       b1   1   0  0
```